# Jest testing Fatal JavaScript invalid size error 174895934 error

Tags: react-native, jestjs, ts-jest

I have been trying to run unit tests using jest. But I keep getting fatal error shown below:

```
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Fatal JavaScript invalid size error 174895934
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0x7ff7b06f7e90
 1: 0x10fa5ae4a node::NodePlatform::GetStackTracePrinter()::$_3::__invoke() [/usr/local/Cellar/node/17.7.1/bin/node]
 2: 0x1101a4a22 V8_Fatal(char const*, ...) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/17.7.1/bin/node]
 3: 0x10fc7b242 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArrayWithFiller(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Oddball>, v8::internal::AllocationType) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/17.7.1/bin/node]
 4: 0x10fdfa930 v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsAccessorBase<v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::FastPackedObjectElementsAccessor, v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsKindTraits<(v8::internal::ElementsKind)2> >::ConvertElementsWithCapacity(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FixedArrayBase>, v8::internal::ElementsKind, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/17.7.1/bin/node]
 5: 0x10fdf9522 v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsAccessorBase<v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::FastPackedObjectElementsAccessor, v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsKindTraits<(v8::internal::ElementsKind)2> >::GrowCapacity(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, unsigned int) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/17.7.1/bin/node]
 6: 0x10ff2cf3d v8::internal::Runtime_GrowArrayElements(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/17.7.1/bin/node]
 7: 0x10f858ff9 Builtins_CEntry_Return1_DontSaveFPRegs_ArgvOnStack_NoBuiltinExit [/usr/local/Cellar/node/17.7.1/bin/node]
error Command failed with signal "SIGTRAP".
```

**package.json**

```
 "ts-jest": "27.0.0",
 "jest": "27.0.0",
```

increasing max heap size did not work. How can I solve it?

Comment: dammit, exactly the same issue running in Github CI environment. with ts-jest, too! and no real answer...

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because of the v8 engine. Decreasing the length of the array helped me. In my case 116597277 (certainly not 32-bit) is the limit for k, but I could not find out why or anything else.

```
const somethingToTest = require('./somethingToTest')

describe('somethingToTest()', () => {    

test('linear array', () => {
    let arraysToTest = []
    const target = 91718346
    for(let i = 1; i<=100000000; i++){
      let littleArray = []
      for(let k = 1; k<=100000000; k++){
        littleArray.push(k)
      }
      arraysToTest.push(littleArray)
    }
    for (const arr of arraysToTest) {
      const expected = arr.indexOf(target)
      const actual = somethingToTest(arr, target)
      expect(actual).toEqual(expected)
    }    
})
```